# With bash build several commands from previous output stream

Tags: bash, xargs, git-clone

I have a bash command that output several repository urls

```
https://repos.com/abc
https://repos.com/def
https://repos.com/ghi
```

I would like to pipe these urls to build several git clone commands such as it executes :

```
git clone https://repos.com/abc
git clone https://repos.com/def
git clone https://repos.com/ghi
```

How shall I do that please ? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the command that outputs the repository URLs? Or at least something equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with 
`xargs -n1 git clone`